# Unterminated `s' command with sed troubleshooting

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a problem with sed. I want to replace the entire specific line number for multiple lines in multiples documents.

This the bash command for 1 specific line in 1 specific document:

```
 BNAME=$(basename $FILE .pdb)
 psfgen1="pdb ./sedpdb/${BNAME}.pdb/"
 sed -i '8s/'.*'/'${psfgen1}'/' ./psfgen.inp
```

And I get this error :
sed: -e expression #1, char 60: unterminated `s' command

Is anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two things wrong:

1. There are forward slashes in the string that you're attempting to use in the sed command. These will be interpreted as part of the command, so you should use a different delimiter.
2. The `*` is unquoted, so will be glob-expanded by the shell to the names of all the files in the directory.

Reliably using shell variables in string substitutions is non-trivial but can be done using one of the approaches shown in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/2088135).

In your case, it looks like you can probably get away with using another character as the delimiter, such as `@`:

```
sed -i "8s@.*@${psfgen1}@" ./psfgen.inp
```

Comment: Thank you ! You are my hero! It's alive!